# Expansion of $x$ in powers of $u$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, power-series, trigonometric-series

Given: 
$$\sin(x) = u \sin(x+a),\qquad  {u<1}$$

How do I expand $x$ in powers of $u$?

I tried using Taylor series but it failed to proceed.

Comment: And you want to expand about $u=0$? I.e. $x(u) = \sum \alpha_i u^i$?

Comment: @user7530 yes I need to expand in ascending powers of u. No condition for u=0 is given in statement. It is just asking me to develop an infinite series.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee That doesn't help. The answer is: usin(a) + (1/2) u^2 sin(2a) and so on......

Comment: @labbhattacharjee your form doesn't gets simplified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did. I started with $\, x_0 := O(u). \,$ Define by recursion
 $\, x_{n+1} := \sin^{-1}(u \sin(x_n + a)). \,$ The first few values are
 $\, x_1 = \sin(a)\, u + O(u^2), \, x_2 = \sin(a)\, u + \sin(2a)\,u^2/2 + O(u^3). \,$
Using the pattern and taking it to the limit, I found that
 $\, x = \log( (1 - u \exp(-ia)) / (1 - u\exp(ia)) )/(2i). \,$ In the limit 
 $\, x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(na)\,u^n/n . \,$

Another method uses exponentials. Let
 $\, X := \exp(i x), \, A := \exp(i a) \,$ 
and substitute them in equation
 $\, \sin(x) = u \sin(x+a) \,$ to get 
 $\, (X - 1/X) = u (X A - 1/(X A)) \,$
and solving for $\, X \,$ gives
 $ X^2 = (1 - u/A) / (1 - A u). \,$ 
Using $\, \log(1-x) = - \sum_{n>0} x^n/n \,$
 now gives the power series in $\, u.$

Comment: Don't know if this is solution is feasible, but it is a brute force way to find the answer

Comment: Ok thank you for helping